# R equivalent to the MATLAB structure?

Tags: r, matlab

Is there an R type equivalent to the Matlab structure type?

I have a few named vectors and I try to store them in a data frame. Ideally, I would simply access one element of an object and it would return the named vectors (like a structure in Matlab). I feel that using a data frame is not the right thing to do since it can store the values of the named vectors but not the names when they differ from one vector to the other.

More generally, is it possible to store a bunch of different objects in a single one in R?

**Edit**: As Joran said I think that `list` does the job.

```
l = list()
l$vec1 = namedVector1
l$vec2 = namedVector2
...
```

If I have a  list of names

```
name1 = 'vec1'
name2 = 'vec2'
```

is there any way for the interpreter to understand that when I use a variable name like name1, I am not referring to the variable name but to its content? I have tried `get(name1)` but it does not work.

Comment: I'm note sure what exactly in Matlab you're talking about, but your options in R are basically: vectors, lists, matrices, data frames, or (if you want to get fancy) environments. My guess if you want a list.

Comment: @joran: [Matlab structure](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/struct.html)

Comment: I'm sure @joran is right (about a `list` being what you want), but I'm confused by the bit about "but not the names when the differ from one vector to the other". To what names are you referring?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien I think he means rownames can't differ across columns in a data.frame.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure there's something _exactly_ like that in R (there rarely is across languages) but if you provided a specific example of what you're trying to do in R, I'm sure we can cook something up that will help you out.

Comment: I have different named vectors which I try to store in a single object. Those named vectors have nothing in common, not the same number of rows, not the same names.

Comment: For the named ones use l[["vec1"]] etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could still be wrong about what you're trying to do, but I think this is the best you're going to get in terms of accessing each list element by name:

```
l <- list(a= 1:3,b = 1:10)
> ind <- "a"
> l[[ind]]
[1] 1 2 3
```

Namely, you're going to have to use `[[` explicitly.

Comment: And FWIW, `get(ind, pos=l)` also works. (Not sure where that would be better than `l[[ind]]`, though.)

Comment: `get(ind, pos=l)` would return `"a"` but how would use that to access `l$a` ?

Comment: @Youcha No, actually, it returns the same thing (or at least it should, and does for me).

Comment: l[[1]] returns 1 2 3 but l["a"] or l[["a"]]  does not work for me? Well it does, but here it doesn't:

all_params <- list(yearly_rental_costs_year_zero,actualisatiepercentage)
 all_params[["actualisatiepercentage"]]

returns null intead of 0.03, what it should be

Comment: @babipsylon try `all_params <- list(y = yearly_rental_costs_year_zero, a = actualisatiepercentage)` and then `all_params[["a"]]`. It should produce the desired output.